# Javascript Reg ex to match a text

Tags: javascript

How do i check if a particular text exists in a word on its own or a part of a word?
I understand the code below but it work separately.Im looking for a single expression that will also return TRUE for tested,retest but False for test0123,123test. Any help much appreciated

```
var string_1 = "test";
var string_2 = "retests";

/\btest\b/g.test(string_1);//TRUE

/\Btest\B/g.test(string_2);//TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
/([^\d]+|\b)test([^\d]+|\b)/g.test(string);
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer mate,is it possible to change the text 'test' in /([^\d]+|\b)test([^\d]+|\b)/g dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the explicit words tested or retest:

```
/\b(tested|retest)\b/gi
```

The word boundaries are still in place around either choice.